# Custom class in Settings.settings only gets saved when the properties are accessed before

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, settings.settings

I'm using the standard [.NET settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) (via the Settings Designer) to store my settings.

I have custom class to combine some settings into something like

```
public CustomSetting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int? SelectionID
    {
        get { return _selectionID; }
        set
        {
            _selectionID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectionID")
        }
    }
    private int? _selectionID;

    ...
}
```

Then I've added one setting with the name `CustomSetting1` to the Settings Designer.

And extended the partial settings class with this

```
public partial class Settings
{
    private Settings()
    {
        // make sure the setting is initialized on first startup
        if (CustomSetting1 == null)
        {
            CustomSetting1 = new CustomSetting();
            Save();
        }            

        CustomSetting1.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => 
            {
                Save();
            };
    }
}
```

This setting has a binding to a `ComboBox` that will change it's value, the `PropertyChanged` event is called when I make a change and `Save()` works without any exception. But when I look into the config file the setting didn't change (but the 'Date modified' has updated).

But now comes the weird part, when I look into the Setting with the debugger, or print it with `Console.WriteLine(CustomSetting1.SelectionID)` before calling the `Save()` function it will magically work.

What can I do about this issue? Except `Console.WriteLine` on every property before calling the `Save()` function...

Comment: where are you looking at the settings file? can you provide the directory path?

Comment: Just the default path that is used by the microsoft .NET settings stuff, I can't influence this.

C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\<Company Name>\<ApplicationName>_<Hash>\<Version>\user.config